# Unable to start python file with http framework on crontab

Tags: python

This is my very first question, so forgive me if I am not correctly following the forum rules ;;))

I am looking to automate a python script for a webpage using GPIO pins that I can remotely enable through the webpage. The thing is that the script requires some sort of GUI to work, otherwise it doesn't start. I use **HTTP.server** library which is very handy and rather simple (I tried flask server as well but since I only need one page I prefer to stick with this) and the main element of the script is the **BaseHTTPRequestHandler** class

In my crontab configuration file, I have added the following line to execute the script on bootup (which happens frequently)
`@reboot python3 -u /home/pi/Desktop/webserver.py`

When I look at crontab logs, here is what appears regarding my python file
`raspberrypi CRON[407]: (root) CMD (python3 -u /home/pi/Desktop/webserver.py )`
I do not get any errors (or at least I don't see them)

But most importantly I know the file doesn't seem to execute
It only works once I run it in a GUI window because it requires some output window to show the logs. As you can see in the extract below, the python script prints text for each HTTP request.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo python3 Desktop/webserver.py
Server Starts - 192.168.1.36:4590
195.68.33.114 - - [10/Feb/2023 15:54:44] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
195.68.33.114 - - [10/Feb/2023 15:54:45] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
195.68.33.114 - - [10/Feb/2023 15:54:46] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Is there any way I could run this script successfully without GUI on crontab, and (ideally) dump the logs in a separate file so that I can still know what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a cron user, and to be fair some people seem to have problems with any and all conventional methods of starting a boot service, but really the most proper is systemd, the [init system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) used by most contemporary GNU/Linux distros including RpiOS.  That's what it is intended for, whereas cron really is not; it's a service in itself intended to run quick (or at finite time wise) tasks as opposed to persistent things that run indefinitely.

Systemd can appear too complicated due to the extent of its features.  This case should not be too difficult, however.  This is an appropriate service file:

```ini
[Unit]                                             
Description=Python HTTP server                     
Requires=local-fs.target                           
Requires=network-online.target                     
After=network-online.target                        
                                                   
[Service]                                          
Type=simple                                        
StandardInput=null                                 
StandardOutput=file:/var/log/pythonHTTP.log        
StandardError=inherit                              
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 -u /home/pi/Desktop/webserver.py 
                                                   
[Install]                                          
WantedBy=default.target
```

The `Requires` and `Wants` are a bit paranoid. You do need the root filesystem mounted read/write, but if you are just starting a server -- which listens on a port but does not try to establish any connections -- then you don't really need the network online first.

All the directives are listed in [`man systemd.directives`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.directives.html) together with their corresponding man page, if you want to look these up.
There are hundreds of systemd man pages.

Anyway, put that in `/etc/systemd/system` (you will need root privileges) with a `.service` suffix, eg. `pythonHTTP.service`, then `sudo systemctl enable pythonHTTP.service`.  This will start it on boot.

You can also start it manually with `sudo systemctl start pythonHTTP`.  This doesn't provide feedback, but you can get that immediately afterward with `sudo systemctl status pythonHTTP` (you can also do this at reboot).  If it failed, that should be clear, hopefully along with enough details to figure out why.

Comment: Yay it worked ! However I just get an error with ```sudo systemd enable pythonHTTP.service```. I get an**Excess arguments.** error. Is that normal ? Many thanks. All I need now is a way to start it automatically on bootup ;)

Comment: Ack!  That should have been `systemctl`, not `systemd`!  Corrected.

Comment: thanks ! ;)))))

Comment: The code fails to start on its own... Very weird ```févr. 11 20:34:05 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Python HTTP server.
févr. 11 20:34:09 raspberrypi systemd[1]: pythonHTTP.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
févr. 11 20:34:09 raspberrypi systemd[1]: pythonHTTP.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
févr. 11 20:34:09 raspberrypi systemd[1]: pythonHTTP.service: Consumed 1.120s CPU time.```

Comment: ok I think I solved the issue. I guess the program was starting before the IP of my raspberry pi was determined, so I justed added 10 seconds before the program starts and it worked !!

Comment: I've never used python's HTTPserver and the docs aren't clear on this, but I've done a lot of low level server programming, and you should try `0.0.0.0` as the `host_name` value.  I think what that is actually for is determing which interface to listen on (eg., `127.0.0.1` will be just the local loopback).  If there's no interface with that `192...` address when it starts, it will probably fail.  `0.0.0.0` causes it to listen on all interfaces (on a Pi normally there are 3, ethernet, wifi, and loopback), which is usually for the best.

Comment: BTW, if this enabled you to solve your problem, please tick the big checkmark on the top left of the answer.

Comment: ha ha... `Systemd can appear too complicated ...` Yes, it appears that way because it is too complicated :)

Comment: No that's **gradle**.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to do this by configuring python logging:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/6386698/1151724

You can use [shell redirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)), as cron executes via a shell (but there may be some [caveats about the syntax](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52332/25985)):

```
@reboot python3 -u /home/pi/Desktop/webserver.py >> /path/to/logfile 2>&1
```

The `2>&1` at the end is important, as the python logger by default writes to the standard *error* stream; this redirects that to the same place as `>>` (which redirects standard *output* stream).

Thus a simplified version of this is:

```
@reboot python3 -u /home/pi/Desktop/webserver.py 2>> /path/to/logfile
```

This redirects only standard error. The first one is bit nicer in that it does deal with standard out, and so will, eg., capture `print()` statements (they will end up interleaved with the log stuff, which is what running a script at a terminal looks like).

**If the script doesn't seem to run at all** and you are not getting any feedback about why (I am not a cron user, so I don't know if it logs errors but you could check `sudo grep cron /var/log/syslog` and see if there is anything there), try wrapping it in a simple shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Redirects all output.
exec &> /path/to/logfile
date

python3 -u /home/pi/Desktop/webserver.py
```

Call this `runserver.sh` or whatever you like and put that in the crontab instead.  The logfile will be created (remove it first if it already exists) with at least the date and time like so: `Sat 11 Feb 09:50:34 EST 2023` at the top.

You may also want to put more logging into the script, eg., a simple `print('Begin')` at the top of main.  If execution fails, you can then trace the issue this way.

Comment: Thanks !
I tried with the ```>> /path/to/logfile 2>&1``` and```2>> /path/to/logfile``` But it still doesn't seem to work (no problem with crontab, but I can't access my webpage, and I know It doesn't work because I can launch another instance in a separate terminal, which would not be possible when another instance already uses my port) Do you have any advice to disable any output coming from the python script ? From my point of view logging the output is a second necessity, actually.... Very weirdly, the http requests aren't printed with the ```print()``` statement in my code so I can't figur

Comment: Are you saying you think the script is not being run at all?

Comment: by the way here is the pythoin file if you want to have a look [link](https://github.com/Oscar-T24/random-stuff

Comment: I think the script is not running at all, but crontab tells me it's actually running ! I think It has to do with the lack of GUI... It never happened to me before

Comment: I get a 404 for the link.

Comment: It should work now. I forgot to make it public

Comment: I've added some stuff to the answer about debugging the failure.

Comment: Thanks for your help !Here is what I get on the cron systemctl status window after applying your changes : ```févr. 11 16:43:22 raspberrypi CRON[389]: (root) CMD (./home/pi/Desktop/server.sh)
févr. 11 16:43:22 raspberrypi CRON[390]: (root) CMD (python3 -u /home/pi/Desktop/ventilateur_l298n.py)
févr. 11 16:43:22 raspberrypi CRON[335]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)``` I get this weird MTA error

Comment: However the shell script does work on its own when I run it in a normal terminal window. I can also see the logs in the txt file (but only when I run it on a terminal window)

Comment: https://cronitor.io/cron-reference/no-mta-installed-discarding-output  <- That seems beyond stupid -- it looks like if you don't have an MTA, there's no way to get whatever message/output/error it concerns.  Maybe there's a reason I don't use cron ;)

Comment: Yeahhhh....do you have any alternative to cron then? Anything that could make it run on bootup?

Comment: Added another answer about that.